# Why does making a new Thread hang in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was testing how many threads my computer can handle before something goes wrong, using the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
    int count = 0;
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write('m'); // make
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => { Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite); }, 1024 * 64);
            Console.Write('s'); // start
            thread.Start();
            Console.Write('p'); // suspend
            thread.Suspend();
            Console.Write('a'); // add
            threads.Add(thread);
            Console.Write(' ');
            Console.WriteLine(count++);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nGot exception of type " + e.GetType().Name);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(count);
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

I was expected the `new Thread(...)` constructor to throw an exception (maybe `OutOfMemoryException`) when the system could not make any more threads, but instead the constructor hangs and never returns.

Instead of the output from the above being

```
...
mspa 67
m
Got exception of type OutOfMemoryException
```

it is rather

```
...
mspa 67
m    <- it hangs while 'm'aking the thread
```

So, the TLDR: **why does `new Thread(...)` hang instead of throw an exception when there are too many threads?**

Comment: If no memory, anything can happen, so don't let memory run out.

Comment: Maybe your computer still has virtual memory and that is why you do not get OutOfMemory exception? Instead you RAM is full but your virtual memory is not and systems starts to use swap file heavily which could cause hang of pc?

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets but other programs work just fine... it's just the program that hangs.

Comment: Hm, strange. Anyway try to monitor IO operations during hang time.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets what do you mean by that, and how I can do it?

Comment: Go to "Task Manager"->"Performance"->"Resource Monitor". Check "Disk" tab.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets there is no disk usage...

Comment: Does it stop at 67 already? Is this a regular kind of OS?

Comment: It can go up into the thousands, on my machine, if I run it without the debugger attached. But if I debug it, it stops at ~47 or ~67. So it's not a fault with `new Thread()`, per se, but something about the debug environment, I think. Can you (@feralin) confirm if you were trying this out in the debugger or not?

Comment: I can make 6000+ sleepy threads on my Vista box, no problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   thread.Suspend();
```

That's an evil, evil, *evil* method.  Strongly deprecated in .NET version 2.0, it isn't very clear how you got past the [Obsolete] message and not notice this.  I'll quote the MSDN note about this method:

> Do not use the Suspend and Resume methods to synchronize the activities of threads. You have no way of knowing what code a thread is executing when you suspend it. If you suspend a thread while it holds locks during a security permission evaluation, other threads in the AppDomain might be blocked. If you suspend a thread while it is executing a class constructor, other threads in the AppDomain that attempt to use that class are blocked. Deadlocks can occur very easily.

Yup, that's what a deadlock looks like.

Comment: Why would the deadlock always happen at exactly the 67'th or 68'th thread creation?

Comment: None of this matters, don't use that method.  Use an unmanaged debugger if you want to find out anyway.